# MongoParseError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864 (NestJS & MongoDB Docker Container)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, microservices, nestjs

I am working on a NestJS Project that is based on micro-service architecture (Kafka, CQRS Patter).

I have created a shared mongodb database inside docker container and exposed the port to 8081 Port which is accessible via browser(I am using mongo-express ui). Here is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.1'

services:
mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: PWD

mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8081:8081
    volumes:
        - data-volume:/data/db
    environment:
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: PWD
volumes:
    data-volume:
```

And in my NESTJS Service, I have defined mongo connection like this: (**app.module.ts**)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { CqrsModule } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [UserModule, MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:8081/urooj', {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useFindAndModify: false,
     useCreateIndex: true
 })],
 controllers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in my user module I am defining User schema: (**user.module.ts**)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CqrsModule } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserHandler  } from "./command/handler/index";
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserSchema } from './models/user.model';
import { UsersRepository } from './user.repository';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
       CqrsModule,
       MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'User', schema: UserSchema}])
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [
       ...UserHandler,
       UserService
    ]
 })
 export class UserModule {}
```

But I am getting this error which I tried finding the solution but i am bit unlucky in solving this issue from quite sometime now.

```
events.js:292
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

MongoParseError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864
    at processIncomingData (/Users/rk/Desktop/workspace/project/service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:118:7)
at MessageStream._write (/Users/rk/Desktop/workspace/project/service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)


at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:716:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
Emitted 'error' event on MessageStream instance at:
at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
at MessageStream.onerror (_stream_readable.js:752:7)
at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:418:5)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:445:5)
at processIncomingData (/Users/rk/Desktop/workspace/project/service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:117:5)
at MessageStream._write (/Users/rk/Desktop/workspace/project/service/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: What is the stack trace for the error?

Comment: @D.SM I have mentioned the stack trace but let me update the entire stack trace.

Comment: You are using a forking server and you have multiple processes reading from the same socket?

Comment: I just created a simple docker container that has mongodb running on it by exposing the port and i am trying to connect to that mongodb using nestjs api. Nothing else is that a problem here?

Comment: This is  a data corruption error. Either you are trying to talk to something that is not a MongoDB server or your client side is broken.

Comment: ok I guess it could be container issue or may be the mongodb exposed port is not working as expected. I will try to debug on this and will update the stack accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this above issue by Exposing Port to mongo service in my docker-compose.yml apart from mongo-express service.

But I ran into another issue now and that is related to authentication when connecting to mongodb using nestjs. Though Mongodb Container can be accessed using compass. I will be debugging this and if required will raise a new question in SO.